# Is there a way for a blob image to load faster after it is fetched?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, axios

I have this form that sends data to my SQL db and a profile image to an S3 bucket. I am fetching that image successfuly and creating a blob element (idk if that's the correct terminology).
The problem here is that my image is taking like 5 seconds to load (not fetch).

I'm very open to suggestions on what I can update/improve, or better ways to do this.

Here is my parser function to handle the image upload and my route to get the image based on id

```
const parsefile = async (req) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let resolved = false;
    let options = {
      maxFileSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024, //100 MBs converted to bytes,
      allowEmptyFiles: false,
    };

    const form = formidable(options);

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {});

    form.on('error', (error) => {
      if (!resolved) {
        resolved = true;
        reject(error.message);
      }
    });

    form.on('data', (data) => {
      if (!resolved && data.name === 'successUpload') {
        resolved = true;
        resolve(data.value);
      }
    });

    form.on('fileBegin', (formName, file) => {
      file.open = async function () {
        this._writeStream = new Transform({
          transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            callback(null, chunk);
          },
        });

        this._writeStream.on('error', (e) => {
          if (!resolved) {
            resolved = true;
            form.emit('error', e);
          }
        });

        // upload to S3
        new Upload({
          client: new S3Client({
            credentials: {
              accessKeyId,
              secretAccessKey,
            },
            region,
          }),
          params: {
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Bucket,
            Key: `${Date.now().toString()}-${this.originalFilename}`,
            Body: this._writeStream,
          },
          tags: [], // optional tags
          queueSize: 4, // optional concurrency configuration
          partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5, // optional size of each part, in bytes, at least 5MB
          leavePartsOnError: false, // optional manually handle dropped parts
        })
          .done()
          .then((data) => {
            if (!resolved) {
              resolved = true;
              form.emit('data', { name: 'complete', value: data });
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            if (!resolved) {
              resolved = true;
              form.emit('error', err);
            }
          });
      };
    });
  });
};
//route for getting the images from the db
router.get('/images/:id', async (req, res) => {
  // Assuming the S3 key is stored in the profile_image_key field
  const cardId = req.params.id;
  
  const s3Client = new S3Client({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey
    },
    region
  });
  // Fetch the card from the database to get the S3 key
  const [card] = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const s3Key = card.profile_image_url;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM cards WHERE id = ?;', [cardId], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });

  if (!card) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Card not found' });
  }

 

  // Fetch the image from S3
  try {
    
    const data = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket, Key: s3Key }));
    const imageInfo = imageType(data.Body);
    const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(data.Body);

    // Set appropriate headers and send the image to the client
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', imageInfo.mime); // Adjust the content type based on your image type
    res.send(imageBuffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(s3Key)
    console.error('Error fetching image from S3:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});
```

Here is my card component (the db data and img are being loaded here

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { S3, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import "./cardcomponent.css"

function CardComponent({ email, phone, company, profile_image_url }) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const accessKeyId = "myaccesskey";
  const secretAccessKey = "secretkey";
  const region = "reg";
  const Bucket = "bucketname";

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImage = async () => {
  try {
    const s3Client = new S3({
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey,
      },
      region: "eu-west-2",
    });

    const key = new URL(profile_image_url).pathname.replace(/^\//, '');
    const getObjectParams = {
      Bucket,
      Key: encodeURIComponent(key),
    };

    const command = new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams);
    const response = await s3Client.send(command);

    // ReadableStream to Uint8Array
    const chunks = [];
    const streamReader = response.Body.getReader();

    while (true) {
      const { done, value } = await streamReader.read();

      if (done) {
        break;
      }

      chunks.push(value);
    }

    const arrayBuffer = chunks.length > 1 ? chunks.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b]) : chunks[0];
    const imageBuffer = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

    // Convert Uint8Array to Blob
    const blob = new Blob([imageBuffer], { type: response.ContentType });

    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    setImage(imageUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
  }
};
   
    fetchImage();

    return () => {
      if(image) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(image);
      }
    }
  }, [profile_image_url, Bucket, region, accessKeyId, secretAccessKey]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Log the rendered HTML of the image element
    console.log('Rendered HTML of Image:', document.querySelector('.card-header img'));

    // Check for any errors in the console
    const errorMessages = document.querySelector('.card-header img').outerHTML.match(/<img .*?alt="Profile".*?>/i);
    if (errorMessages) {
      console.error('Image Error Messages:', errorMessages);
    }
  }, [image]);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-header">
        {/* Log the imageUrl to the console */}
        {console.log('Render Image URL:', image)}
        <img src={image} alt="Profile" />
      </div>
      <div className="card-body">
        <h3>{company}</h3>
        <p>Email: {email}</p>
        <p>Phone: {phone}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

CardComponent.propTypes = {
  email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  phone: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  company: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  profile_image_url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default CardComponent;
```

This is my first time doing this, so it might not be the best way of doing so, I'm VERY open to suggestions.

I have tried changing the blob thing to 64based enconding, but it stopped working and I couldn't figure out why or how.

Thanks in advance guys.

I tried to use other encondings but with not avail.